# Python Twisted using argparse module

Tags: python, parsing, command, twisted

I'm building Python Twisted applications and would like to use the argparse module to parse command line options, instead of the Twisted usage.Options, which seems kind of old school.

I'd like to run the app with twistd, and am concerned about argparse interfering with twistd's command line argument parsing. I am seeking pointers, suggestions or opinions on what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your [`twistd` plugins](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/tap.html) are required to parse command-line options by providing a class with a `parseOptions` method that takes an argv-style list.  Beyond that, what you do is up to you.  If you supply a class with that method that calls into `argparse`, great.

Comment: Thanks Jean-Paul. Can you help me further? I'm not sure what you mean by "twistd plugins are required to parse command-line options..." Most of the Twisted I've written has used the reactor directly rather than the Twisted Application object and twistd (don't get me started about why I'm doing this <g>). Can you point me to some documentation about twistd plugins?

Comment: I added a link to the `twistd` plugin documentation to the answer.

Comment: Thanks Glyph, I'll do some more reading of the documentation you've linked to.